# Customizing an InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

Is it possible to change the color of the border, the alignment, padding and other attributes of an InfoWindow? I've been looking for this for a week but I always end up [here](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow_custom/infowindow-custom.html). And it does not provide a code.

Here's my code.

```
        //Declare an infoWindow variable - shows when a marker is tapped/clicked
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
        downloadUrl("outputXML.php", function(data)
        {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
            var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
            var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
            var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: icon.icon,
                title:name
                });
            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
            }
       });               
        
        function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              infoWindow.setContent(html);
              infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
          }

          function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
                new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
                new XMLHttpRequest;

            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (request.readyState == 4) {
                request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                callback(request, request.status);
              }
            };

            request.open('GET', url, true);
            request.send(null);
          }//END FUNCTION BINDINFOWINDOW
        
            function doNothing() {} //For request.onreadystatechange
```

By the way, I'm catching those values from an online database, we don't have to mind that, they're all working fine, the only problem is how to customize an infoWindow.

Please help me. Thanks.

ADD: I forgot to say that I will insert this into an android application. I'm using webview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content that you pass to an `InfoWindow` may be: text, HTML, or a DOM element. The `InfoWindow` is by default sized to fit whataver content you pass, so the best way to control the content the way you describe is to create a `div`, assign a CSS class to the `div`, and then you will have complete control over the appearance of your `InfoWindow` content.

Also, if you want to have more control over the actual appearance of the window structure itself, you may want to consider using the [InfoBubble Utility Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#InfoBubble) as a stylable drop-in replacement for the standard `InfoWindow`.

Comment: Yes, I am catching String from the database and convert it to an HTML format. I'll try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the sample code of this [url](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow_custom/infowindow-custom.html),

In this code, InfoBox extends GOverlay class from the Google Maps API and creating div dynamically and drawing into the map.

Another [Example page](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Info Window Custom</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

/* An InfoBox is like an info window, but it displays
 * under the marker, opens quicker, and has flexible styling.
 * @param {GLatLng} latlng Point to place bar at
 * @param {Map} map The map on which to display this InfoBox.
 * @param {Object} opts Passes configuration options - content,
 *   offsetVertical, offsetHorizontal, className, height, width
 */
function InfoBox(opts) {
  google.maps.OverlayView.call(this);
  this.latlng_ = opts.latlng;
  this.map_ = opts.map;
  this.offsetVertical_ = -195;
  this.offsetHorizontal_ = 0;
  this.height_ = 165;
  this.width_ = 266;

  var me = this;
  this.boundsChangedListener_ =
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.map_, "bounds_changed", function() {
      return me.panMap.apply(me);
    });

  // Once the properties of this OverlayView are initialized, set its map so
  // that we can display it.  This will trigger calls to panes_changed and
  // draw.
  this.setMap(this.map_);
}

/* InfoBox extends GOverlay class from the Google Maps API
 */
InfoBox.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

/* Creates the DIV representing this InfoBox
 */
InfoBox.prototype.remove = function() {
  if (this.div_) {
    this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
    this.div_ = null;
  }
};

/* Redraw the Bar based on the current projection and zoom level
 */
InfoBox.prototype.draw = function() {
  // Creates the element if it doesn't exist already.
  this.createElement();
  if (!this.div_) return;

  // Calculate the DIV coordinates of two opposite corners of our bounds to
  // get the size and position of our Bar
  var pixPosition = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng_);
  if (!pixPosition) return;

  // Now position our DIV based on the DIV coordinates of our bounds
  this.div_.style.width = this.width_ + "px";
  this.div_.style.left = (pixPosition.x + this.offsetHorizontal_) + "px";
  this.div_.style.height = this.height_ + "px";
  this.div_.style.top = (pixPosition.y + this.offsetVertical_) + "px";
  this.div_.style.display = 'block';
};

/* Creates the DIV representing this InfoBox in the floatPane.  If the panes
 * object, retrieved by calling getPanes, is null, remove the element from the
 * DOM.  If the div exists, but its parent is not the floatPane, move the div
 * to the new pane.
 * Called from within draw.  Alternatively, this can be called specifically on
 * a panes_changed event.
 */
InfoBox.prototype.createElement = function() {
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  var div = this.div_;
  if (!div) {
    // This does not handle changing panes.  You can set the map to be null and
    // then reset the map to move the div.
    div = this.div_ = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.border = "0px none";
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    div.style.background = "url('http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/images/blueinfowindow.gif')";
    div.style.width = this.width_ + "px";
    div.style.height = this.height_ + "px";
    var contentDiv = document.createElement("div");
    contentDiv.style.padding = "30px"
    contentDiv.innerHTML = "<b>Hello World! </b>";

    var topDiv = document.createElement("div");
    topDiv.style.textAlign = "right";
    var closeImg = document.createElement("img");
    closeImg.style.width = "32px";
    closeImg.style.height = "32px";
    closeImg.style.cursor = "pointer";
    closeImg.src = "http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/images/closebigger.gif";
    topDiv.appendChild(closeImg);

    function removeInfoBox(ib) {
      return function() {
        ib.setMap(null);
      };
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(closeImg, 'click', removeInfoBox(this));

    div.appendChild(topDiv);
    div.appendChild(contentDiv);
    div.style.display = 'none';
    panes.floatPane.appendChild(div);
    this.panMap();
  } else if (div.parentNode != panes.floatPane) {
    // The panes have changed.  Move the div.
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    panes.floatPane.appendChild(div);
  } else {
    // The panes have not changed, so no need to create or move the div.
  }
}

/* Pan the map to fit the InfoBox.
 */
InfoBox.prototype.panMap = function() {
  // if we go beyond map, pan map
  var map = this.map_;
  var bounds = map.getBounds();
  if (!bounds) return;

  // The position of the infowindow
  var position = this.latlng_;

  // The dimension of the infowindow
  var iwWidth = this.width_;
  var iwHeight = this.height_;

  // The offset position of the infowindow
  var iwOffsetX = this.offsetHorizontal_;
  var iwOffsetY = this.offsetVertical_;

  // Padding on the infowindow
  var padX = 40;
  var padY = 40;

  // The degrees per pixel
  var mapDiv = map.getDiv();
  var mapWidth = mapDiv.offsetWidth;
  var mapHeight = mapDiv.offsetHeight;
  var boundsSpan = bounds.toSpan();
  var longSpan = boundsSpan.lng();
  var latSpan = boundsSpan.lat();
  var degPixelX = longSpan / mapWidth;
  var degPixelY = latSpan / mapHeight;

  // The bounds of the map
  var mapWestLng = bounds.getSouthWest().lng();
  var mapEastLng = bounds.getNorthEast().lng();
  var mapNorthLat = bounds.getNorthEast().lat();
  var mapSouthLat = bounds.getSouthWest().lat();

  // The bounds of the infowindow
  var iwWestLng = position.lng() + (iwOffsetX - padX) * degPixelX;
  var iwEastLng = position.lng() + (iwOffsetX + iwWidth + padX) * degPixelX;
  var iwNorthLat = position.lat() - (iwOffsetY - padY) * degPixelY;
  var iwSouthLat = position.lat() - (iwOffsetY + iwHeight + padY) * degPixelY;

  // calculate center shift
  var shiftLng =
      (iwWestLng < mapWestLng ? mapWestLng - iwWestLng : 0) +
      (iwEastLng > mapEastLng ? mapEastLng - iwEastLng : 0);
  var shiftLat =
      (iwNorthLat > mapNorthLat ? mapNorthLat - iwNorthLat : 0) +
      (iwSouthLat < mapSouthLat ? mapSouthLat - iwSouthLat : 0);

  // The center of the map
  var center = map.getCenter();

  // The new map center
  var centerX = center.lng() - shiftLng;
  var centerY = center.lat() - shiftLat;

  // center the map to the new shifted center
  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(centerY, centerX));

  // Remove the listener after panning is complete.
  google.maps.event.removeListener(this.boundsChangedListener_);
  this.boundsChangedListener_ = null;
};

function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.397, 150.644),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      sensor: 'true'
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34, 150),
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
      var infoBox = new InfoBox({latlng: marker.getPosition(), map: map});
    });
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, "click");
  }
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```